# Javascript - How to use a variable across two functions in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have to migrate old, plain HTML with plain JS files to `webpack` but I have troubles when I have a variable declared outside functions and used between multiple functions below them.

One of the example:

```
// import stuff

var recorder;
var blobs = [];

function recordStart() {
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(...);
  blobs = []
  recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    console.log("recording");
    if (event.data) blobs.push(event.data);
  };
  recorder.onstop = function(){...};
  recorder.start();
}

function recordEnd() {
  recorder.stop();
}

$('#capture_button').on('touchstart mousedown', function() {
  recordStart();
})
$('#capture_button').on('touchend mouseup', function() {
  recordEnd();
})
```

However, everytime `recordEnd` is called, JS console always throw `undefined` error on `recorder` object, as if the variable never even touched at all by the `recordStart` function.

Is there something that I do wrong here? I just learn `webpack` for a week so please bear with me if this is a rookie mistake.

PS. jQuery runs fine, if I run `console.log()` in them they would fire properly.

Edit: I forgot to mention this issue happens only after I run `npx webpack` on it with this configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|glb|gltf|usdz)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from: "src/images", to: "images"},
        {from: "src/maps", to: "maps"},
        {from: "src/models", to: "models"}
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

It runs well before I migrate to `webpack`, but after I bundled with it and include the `dist/bundle.js` in the HTML in `dist/index.html` the `undefined` error happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Webpack Title</title>
  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of just `var recorder;`, why don't you declare `var recorder = new MediaRecorder(...);`? That should ensure it's always defined.

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with webpack if all that is in the same file. Once I clean up your code to actually run, it seems to work fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-river-ho0di?file=/src/index.js Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem you are having?

Comment: Have you tried running through this in the debugger?

Comment: @AlexWayne I added some context to the issue, sorry I forgot the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main selling points of modules is to give your code an explicit dependency chain, and to avoid global variables. For variables that you want to be able to access in other modules, you should `export` them, and `import` them where they're needed.

```
export let recorder;
// do stuff
// assign to recorder
```

and in the other module

```
import { recorder } from './theFirstModule';
function recordEnd() {
  recorder.stop();
}
```

The other (bad) option is to make `recorder` explicitly global, so it'll be accessible anywhere - but that defeats the purpose of using modules and makes code harder to reason about, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead of doing

```
var recorder;
```

, instead, wherever you assign to `recorder`, assign to `window.recorder`. (But if I were you I'd really try working within the module system first)

Comment: It works like charm! Turns out I have to export the variables one by one instead of using `module.exports = {}`. Thanks for the spot on example!